# How do I draw separate windows that show what I would like?

Tags: java, windows

I'm looking to make it so I have a separate window that would show anything, but for my purpose I would like it to show things like the location of objects, their status(whether they have collided with something etc) and so on, the problem is, I have no idea how to go about this.

I would use `System.out.println("Stuff: " + thing);` but the information would move up too fast.

I made and awesome image to somewhat illustrate what I'm after.

[image]

(Edit)
So what I'm looking for is how to make two separate windows like in the picture. They are separate, yet still the one program. The blank behind it is the desktop(Which I should have made a bit more clear) The 2nd debug window can do anything the main window can(By that I mean it can render shapes, images and such). All I'm asking is, how do I achieve this?

What on this would I add/change and where, to make it work?

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
    JFrame frame;
    Graphics2D g2d;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Game();
    }

    public Game()
    {       
        frame = new JFrame();

        setTitle("Battle for the Roids");
        setSize(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        // Set up assets and initialize loop
    }

    // Lots of lines later

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        // Set up double/triple buffering
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null)
        {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();

        // Add things to be rendered

        g2d.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
}
```

I have lots of extra code in there but nothing that would be required. Mostly moving, rotating, key handling etc code.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at logging framework, for example, log4j. I think that would be easier, as you seem to be only interesting in using it to log debug information.

Comment: I think you may need to add a bit more detail about what it is you've tried to do. Consider expanding your question.

Answer (score 2):

Idk if this would help you or not, but what you could possibly do is create a new JFrame and have it appear using another class. Create a JLabel object, and have it set all the information for how ever many objects you need to use.

For example, if you want to have it show the user data you might wanna try:

```
 public class WindowSample extends JFrame {
    JLabel userData = new JLabel();
    add(userData);
    userData.setText(//information for user data);
 }
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Log4J and write your own appender whose sole responsibility was to output to something like `JTextArea` or `JList`, this would decouple the two halves of your application.  Then all you would need to do would be to use the `Logger` to write information about the state of your application.

If that didn't meet your needs, you could write some kind of listener/observer/call-back API that linked into your game model.

You would then be able to respond to changes to the model directly.  This has the draw back of potentially slowing you game engine, as it would need to fire updates any time any part of the application changed.

You could over come this by using a separate thread to dispatch these events, but that's still adding overhead.

Personally, I like the second option, but the first is easier to implement ;)

Comment: +1, I liked both the approaches, presented by you. Though both of them demands careful implementation :-)